# A lucky proof for the Basel problem.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, improper-integrals

I'll modify this part since I want the proof to be here.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac43\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=-\frac43\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 x^{2n}\ln x dx=\frac43\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx\overset{x\rightarrow \frac{1}{x}}=\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac23 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{(x+1)(x-1)}dx$$

$$=\frac23 I(1,-1)=\frac23 \frac{\ln^2 (1)-\ln^2(-1)}{2(1-(-1))}=\frac23 \frac{\pi^2}{4}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Where we considered the following integral:
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{(x+a)(x+b)}dx\overset{x\rightarrow  \frac{ab}{x}}=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln\left(\frac{ab}{x}\right)}{(x+a)(x+b)}dx$$
Summing up the two integrals from above gives:
$$2I(a,b)=\ln(ab)\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x+a)(x+b)}dx=\frac{\ln(ab)}{a-b}\ln\left(\frac{x+b}{x+a}\right)\bigg|_0^\infty $$
$$\Rightarrow I(a,b)=\frac{\ln(ab)}{2}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{a-b}=\frac{\ln^2 a-\ln^2 b}{2(a-b)}$$

---

From [here](https://ysharificalc.wordpress.com/2019/05/01/integral-of-lnx-x-1xa/) we know that:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{(x+a)(x-1)}dx=\frac{\ln^2 a+\pi^2}{2(a+1)} $$

Also by plugging $b=-1$ in $I(a,b)$ we get:
$$I(a,-1)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{(x+a)(x-1)}dx=\frac{\ln^2a -\ln^2 (-1)}{2(a-(-1))}=\frac{\ln^2 a+\pi^2 }{2(a+1)}$$

We already know that this is true from the linked post, but let's ignore it, since the linked post uses the Basel problem to prove the result.

> Can someone prove rigorously that we are allowed to plug in $b=-1$ in order to get the correct result?

Comment: I always get queasy when improper integrals are manipulated purely symbolically.

Comment: @Randall what do you mean by that? What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your question.  I just get worried when improper integrals are broken up and rearranged with sum-rules without explicitly examining convergence.

Comment: If one can express I(a,-1) in function of zeta(2), one continues with usual methods to compute zeta(2)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fixing $a >0$, we see that the integral
\begin{align*}
f(z) := \int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{(x+a)(x+z)} dx.
\end{align*} converges absolutely for $z$ away from $(-\infty,0]$. So $f$ defines an analytic function on $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0]$ (which can be checked by Morera's theorem and Fubini's theorem, for example.) This implies
$$
f(z) = \frac{\log^2 a - \log^2 z}{2(a-z)}
$$ holds not only on $(0,\infty)$ but also $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0]$ by analytic continuation.
Now we need to check the continuity of $f$ at $z=-1$. Let 
$$
F(x) = \int_1^x \frac{ \log t}{(t+a)(t-1)} dt,\quad x\ge 0
$$ so that $F(\infty) - F(0) $ is the desired integral $\displaystyle I(a) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{(x+a)(x-1)} dx$. By integration by parts,
\begin{align*}
f(z) =& \left[F(x)\frac{ x-1}{x+z}\right]^\infty _0 - (1+z)\int_0^\infty \frac{F(x)}{(x+z)^2} dx\\
=& \left(F(\infty) +\frac{F(0)}{z} \right)- (1+z)\int_0^\infty \frac{F(x)}{(x+z)^2} dx,\quad z\neq 0
\end{align*} The first term tends to $I(a)$ as $z\to -1$. For $z=-1+it, t>0$, the second term can be estimated as
\begin{align*}
|1+z|\left|\int_0^\infty \frac{F(x)}{(x+z)^2} dx\right| \le& t \int_0^\infty \frac{|F(x)|}{|x-1+it|^2} dx \\
\le& \int_0^\infty \frac{t}{(x-1)^2 + t^2} |F(x)| dx\\
&\xrightarrow{t\to 0} \pi |F(1)| = 0.
\end{align*} Thus
$$
 I(a)= \lim_{t\to 0^+} f(-1+it) =\frac{\log^2 a +\pi^2}{2(1+a)} .
$$
**Note** that this argument only works for $z=-1$ since $\displaystyle F(x) =\int_c^x \frac{\log t}{(t+a)(t-c)} dt$ is not well-defined (due to the singularity at $t=c$) for $c>0, c\ne 1$.

Comment: This looks clean, thank you! Also can you please take a look at the comments from here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3305543/515527 ? Is my explanation correct to the fact that we should take the right-most equality from $ I(a,b)=\frac{\ln(ab)}{2}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{a-b}=\frac{\ln^2 a-\ln^2 b}{2(a-b)}$ and not the first one since we don't get rid of the imaginary part?

Comment: @ㄴㄱ I think we can see the validity of the first equality this way. Note I took limit along $z= -1 + it$ as $t\to 0^+$ in my answer, because it may be potentially risky to take $\log (-1)=\pi i$ perfunctorially and there are other possible candidates for this value, such as $-\pi i$ or even $\pm 3\pi i$, etc. That's why we use branch cut of complex log and I took the limit approach. If we take the same limit $z=-1+it, t\to 0^+$, then the first equation would give the correct result -

Comment: $$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\frac{\log(-a-i\epsilon)\log(-a+ i\epsilon)}{2(a+1-\epsilon)} = \frac{\left(\log a-\pi i\right)\left(\log a + \pi i\right)}{2(a+1)} = \frac{\ln^2 a + \pi^2}{2(a+1)}.$$ (Or we can take limit as $z=-1+it, t\to 0^-$ to get the same result.) And according to Dave's answer, for general principal value integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{(x+a)(x-b)}dx$, we should take two sided limit $\lim_{t \to 0^+}\frac{f(-b+it) + f(-b-it)}2.$

Comment: @MyunghyunSong Thank you very much for your solution, it is fascinating! There is only one part that I can't understand and it is the following (it is in red) \begin{align*}
\le& \int_0^\infty \frac{t}{(x-1)^2 + t^2} |F(x)| dx\\
&\xrightarrow{t\to 0} \pi \color{red}{|F(1)|} = 0.
\end{align*} Where does that $|F(1)|$ come from? I was thinking of bounding $F(x)$ higher but $F$ is increasing so I couldn't. Can you help me understand that part?

Answer (score 9):

1. In fact, the equation $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x\mathrm{d}x}{(x+a)(x+b)}=\frac{(\ln a)^2-(\ln b)^2}{2(a-b)}$$ holds for all distinct complex $a$, $b$ not lying on the nonpositive real axis, as follows immediately from the contour integral representation $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x\mathrm{d}x}{(x+a)(x+b)}=-\int_H\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\frac{(\ln x)^2}{2(x-a)(x-b)}\text{.}$$ Here $H$ is a [Hankel contour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_contour) about the negative real axis—where the branch cut of $\ln$ is chosen to be.
2. Even if $b<0$, we may consider the Cauchy principal value $$\mathrm{P}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x\mathrm{d}x}{(x+a)(x-\lvert b\rvert)}\text{.}$$ In this case, we may use the Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem to arrive at $$\mathrm{P}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x\mathrm{d}x}{(x+a)(x-\lvert b\rvert)}=\frac{(\ln a)^2-(\ln \lvert b\rvert )^2+\pi^2}{2(a+\lvert b\rvert)}\text{.}$$
3. If we let $b=-1$, then the integral converges and is equal to its Cauchy principal value. Therefore $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x\mathrm{d}x}{(x+a)(x-1)}=\frac{(\ln a)^2+\pi^2}{2(a+1)}\text{.}$$

Comment: In $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x\mathrm{d}x}{(x+a)(x+b)}=\frac{(\log a)^2-(\log b)^2}{2(a-b)}$ it is the branch of $\log$ analytic on $\Bbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$ which is $\ln $ on $(0,\infty$), then you can say $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x\mathrm{d}x}{x^2-1}=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x\mathrm{d}x}{(x+1)(x-1+i\epsilon)}$

Answer (score 8):

Here is an elementary proof.

\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{(x+c)(x-1)}dx \\
= & \ \frac{c-1}{c+1} \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x }{(x+c)(x+1)}dx + \frac{2}{c+1} \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx \\
=& \ \frac{c-1}{c+1}\cdot \frac{\ln^2 c}{2(c-1)}
 + \frac{2}{c+1} \cdot \frac{\pi^2}4
= \frac{\pi^2 + \ln^2 c+ \pi^2}{2(c+1)}
\end{align}

where

\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x }{(x+c)(x+1)}
\overset{t=\frac cx}{dx}=\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln c }{(t+c)(t+1)}dt= \frac{\ln^2 c}{2(c-1)}\tag{2}\\
&\int_0^\infty 
\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx
=\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{y}{1+(x^2-1)y^2}dy\>dx
=\int_0^1 \frac{\frac\pi2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dy=\frac{\pi^2}4
\end{align}

Comment: How did you even come up with something like this? Also it's t = c/x not t= 1/x

Comment: @symmetrickittens - thanks, corrected