# How substitution can I use to get $ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(\frac{1-x}{1+x})}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=4\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log (y)}{1-y^2} dy $?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I found it from a exercise book that the following integral
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(\frac{1-x}{1+x})}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
$$
can be calculated by certain substitution: 
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(\frac{1-x}{1+x})}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx
=4\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log (y)}{1-y^2} dy\tag{1}
$$
The book does not provides any details what substitution is used.

**Question**: What substitution should I use to get (1)?

Comment: Ya,it was a typo,thanka for figuring out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that there is a missing factor of $4$.

The substitution is pretty much there as the argument of the logarithm:$$\frac{1-x}{1+x}=t\Rightarrow x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}\Rightarrow dx=-\frac{2}{(1+t)^2}dt$$
$$\Rightarrow \int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{\sqrt t (1-t)}dt\overset{t=y^2}=4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln y}{1-y^2}dy$$
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3306956/515527) is a way to solve the last integral in case one's interested.