# Help with a limit about $F(x) = \displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{ \log t}{(t+a)(t-1)} dt$

Tags: integration, solution-verification, improper-integrals

I was looking at [this beautiful answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3307129/691503), but I got stuck almost at the end of the demonstration, I've been thinking about how to solve it for days but I can't, could you help me understand it?
The function is defined $F(x) = \displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{ \log t}{(t+a)(t-1)} dt,\quad x\ge 0$. I copy just the part that interests me (red is what he couldn't see):
For $z=-1+it, t>0$, the second term can be estimated as
\begin{align*}
|1+z|\left|\int_0^\infty \frac{F(x)}{(x+z)^2} dx\right| \le& t \int_0^\infty \frac{|F(x)|}{|x-1+it|^2} dx \\
\le& \int_0^\infty \frac{t}{(x-1)^2 + t^2} |F(x)| dx\\
&\xrightarrow{t\to 0} \pi \color{red}{|F(1)|} = 0.
\end{align*}

For a moment I thought I could overbound $|F(x)|$ with some $C$ such that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{(x-1)^2 + t^2} |F(x)| dx&\le C \int_0^\infty \frac{t}{(x-1)^2 + t^2}dx\\
&=C\cdot \arctan(\frac{x-1}{t})\Big|_0^{+\infty}\\
&=C\cdot (\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan \frac{1}{t})
\end{align*}
If $t\to 0^+$ then we would have $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{(x-1)^2 + t^2} |F(x)| dx\le \pi C$. But that would suggest that the upper bound $C$ is $|F(1)|=0$. Which I don't understand why. Maybe my ideas are wrong, could someone throw me a lifeline with this?

Comment: To answer the question that you add in the comment section of the answer of @Ninad, $$\left|f_n(x)\right|\le \frac{C}{1 + x^2} = g(x)$$ where $C$ is an upper bound of $|F|$.

Comment: @Kroki Thanks for your comment, so my idea of how to apply the dominated convergence theorem is correct?

Comment: Yes totally correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply let $x-1 = tu$:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{(x-1)^2+t^2}|F(x)|dx = \int_{-\frac{1}{t}}^\infty \frac{t^2}{t^2u^2+t^2}|F(tu+1)|du$$

$$\longrightarrow \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+u^2}|F(1)|du = \pi|F(1)|$$

as $t\to0^+$ by dominated convergence.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with using dominated convergence but I'm thinking about the following: $$\int_{-\frac{1}{t}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+u^2} |F(tu+1)|du=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{1+u^2}|F(\frac{u}{n}+1)|\chi_{ (-n,\infty)}$$ then I have in mind that $f_n(u)=\frac{1}{1+u^2}|F(\frac{u}{n}+1)|\chi_ {(-n,\infty)}$, so that $f_n(x)\to f(x)=\frac{F(1)}{1+u^2}$.

Comment: But it would be necessary to find the non-negative function $g$ such that $|f_n(x)|\le g(x)$. I got a little lost here... or am I going the wrong way?